# Determine which level of the hierarchy structure

Tags: sql, if-statement, case

I have a SQL statement which contains the following prompts:

```
@deptCode = '0'
@dirCode = '%'
@divCode = '%'
@distCode = '%'
@CCCode = '%'
```

I want to identify the level of the hierarchy. For example in this case I want the return value to be `dept`. If `deptcode = '0'` and `dircode = '3'` the return value should be `dir` and so on.

I'm unsure of the best way of achieving this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what hierarchy you're talking about. You have an SQL statement with variables that you set, and now you want to know what variable is the highest? Shouldn't you know already since you set them?

Comment: please put your complete code with proper information...

Comment: The variables are set dynamically.  Users are able to click on each level of the structure via a breadcrumb function.